# void function return (NULL)

Tags: c

I am looking at a C client-server program and encountered this problem. The compiler complains that the function "return with a value, in function returning void".

My question is, what is the point of returning (NULL) as opposed to simply return? Is this perhaps to avoid the caller from getting garbage back?

```
void *ThreadMain(void *threadArgs)
{
    int clntSock;                   /* Socket descriptor for client connection */

    /* Guarantees that thread resources are deallocated upon return */
    pthread_detach(pthread_self()); 

    /* Extract socket file descriptor from argument */
    clntSock = ((struct ThreadArgs *) threadArgs) -> clntSock;
    free(threadArgs);              /* Deallocate memory for argument */

    HandleTCPClient(clntSock);

    return (NULL);
}
```

Comment: That can't be the function you get the complaint about, as it's declared to return `void *`, i.e. a general pointer.

Comment: This has to do with how thread dispatching works, most likely with pthreads.

Comment: why are you returning a void pointer? replace the 'void *' with 'void' then try using 'return' instead of 'return (NULL)'

Comment: @NicolasBrown the reason the OP is returning a pointer is because of how `pthread_create` is declared, which takes a function pointer returning a pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 "return with a value, in function returning void".
```

You have some other function which has a return type `void` and you are returning a value from that function. But the function you posted is not *that* function. Basically the function you have posted has nothing to do with your problem :)

The one you posted has a return type `void *` which is different from `void`. So this is not the function the compiler complains about. Look at other functions in your code that return `void` (not `void *`) and you have a return in one (or more) of them.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys. It was just a mismatch in function declaration/definition after all. Oops :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason to return `NULL` is to return a pointer to "nothing".

Answer (score 0):

He's returning NULL because the "contract" says he must return a pointer, and he apparently can't/doesn't want to change the contract.